# Ext.js4 -- Adding a box to the top of a panel rather than to the bottom

Tags: extjs, extjs4, panel

I am using Ext.js 4.  I have a panel which contains log messages returned from the server.

The following will append the most recent messages to the that panel:

```
// show log on the log panel
logPanel.add( { xtype: 'box', autoEl: { cn: theText } } );
```

I also add a separator bar between messages:

```
// add a separator bar
logPanel.add( { xtype: 'box', autoEl: { html: '<hr/>'} } );
```

I thought about clearing the panel before adding new messages, so only the most recent messages appear, and this works (when placed before the above):

```
// the following will remove prior log messages...
logPanel.removeAll();
```

But what I would really like to do is simply put the most recent messages BEFORE the previous messages (the default action of the add method is AFTER).

Any suggestions on how I could do that?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the insert method: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-insert